# Clarity with method overriding

Tags: java, overriding

Was curious about the correct definition of the overridden method and the overriding method.
In my understanding the overriding method is the method in the subclass that overrides the method with same signature and return type in the base class.

I have however seen sources refer to the overridden method as being the method in the subclass that overrides the method in the base class.

So which is the overridden method and which is the overriding method?

Sorry if this is a bit of a silly question

Comment: Don't forget to accept one answer as the correct one! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct example from the [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) :

```
public class Animal {
    public static void testClassMethod() {
        System.out.println("The class" + " method in Animal.");
    }
    public void testInstanceMethod() {
        System.out.println("The instance " + " method in Animal.");
    }
}



public class Cat extends Animal {
    public static void testClassMethod() {
        System.out.println("The class method" + " in Cat.");
    }
    public void testInstanceMethod() {
        System.out.println("The instance method" + " in Cat.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat myCat = new Cat();
        Animal myAnimal = myCat;
        Animal.testClassMethod();
        myAnimal.testInstanceMethod();
    }
}
```

The reason I used this example is, look at the scenario from your real-world situation. A `Animal` might have certain general features. But a `Cat` will have some features that are different from a generic `Animal` , but certain features that are an improvement over the generic `Animal` features. So, the `Cat` seems to override (will contain the overriding methods) the `Animal` features.

Another simple example if you are interested in cars. Say, there is a `Car` . It'll have an `acceleration` method. But a `Ferrari` will obviously have a better `acceleration` than a `Car`. But, a `Ferrari` is a `Car`. So, `Ferrari` overrides a method in `Car`. SO, overriding method is in subclass and the overriden method is in the base class.

So, do you get the point now? Overriding methods are present in the subclasses. But the methods that are overriden are present in the base class.

Answer (score 3):

```
class A {
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("I don't know if I am overriden, but I'm not overriding anything");
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("I am overriding A.method() which has now been overriden");
    }
}
```

You can also read the section of the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8) that describes overriding, implementing, hiding, overloading etc. for more in depth understanding.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume we have a `class SubClass extends SuperClass`, then:

```
SuperClass#method   <- overridden
          ^
          |
       overrides
          |
  SubClass#method   <- overriding
```

Apart from that, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Override_%28object-oriented_programming%29) tells us:

> The implementation in the subclass overrides (replaces) the implementation in the superclass by providing a method that has same name, same parameters or signature, and same return type as the method in the parent class.